# How to change the name of a new .zip file automatically?

Tags: c#, automation, zip

I want to implement a function, that will take files from one directory, compress them in .zip and put that archive in another one directory. The problem is that if i call this function more than once, i have to define the name of a new .zip file in code manually, so that it must be always unique. Otherwise i get an exception "System.IO.IOException: 'The destination file already exists.' 
How could i make it so, that a name for every new .zip will be generate automatically?(e.g. new_zip_1, new_zip_2, etc.)

I use a function that allows to make .zip file in choosen directory:

ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);

```
class ZipController
{
    public void Zip()
    {
        string startPath = @"D:\Start\ToZip";
        string zipPath = @"D:\NewZip";

        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can test if file exist before and increment your name with a number until file doesn't exist and create it.

Comment: 1. if you are not creating the files at the same moment, you can include the date and time in the name (e.g. zip_20190508_123702 - format zip_yyyyMMdd_HHmmss). 2. If you need sequential numbering than look here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/32327/128213

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it dos not have to be a incrementing number in the name of the ZIP so I would use date and time. It is less code and it is much more unlike to get the same filename twice.

To get date and time in a filename friendly format:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm-ss")
```

So your code could look like this:

```
class ZipController
{
    public void Zip()
    {
        string startPath = @"D:\Start\ToZip";
        string dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm-ss");
        string zipPath = @"D:\NewZip\new_zip_" + dateTime + ".zip";

        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);
    }
}
```